# Type mismatch error for @RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)

Tags: maven, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Below is my sample runner file. I am getting error in CucmberWithSerenity as below.

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<CucumberWithSerenity> to Class <? extends Runner>

How to resolve this issue?

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/features")
```

Comment: What are your imports?

Answer (score 0):

You have issue with your serenity versions in the pom. Use these below versions:

```
        <serenity.version>2.3.10</serenity.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>2.3.10</serenity.maven.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>2.3.10</serenity.cucumber.version>
```

Add these below dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-ensure</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber6</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then the import class should be good.

Comment: Importing **only** `serenity-cucumber6` will bring in the others as transitive dependencies, guaranteeing you have matching versions. You do need to explicitly specify the others!